# How to delete rows in which only the first column is full?

Tags: linux, text-processing

I have a data file looks like:

```
1 2 3 4
5
6
7
8 9
10 11
12 13
14
15 16 17
18 19 20 21
```

I want to delete all the rows in which only the first column is full. so output should be :

```
1 2 3 4
8 9
10 11
12 13
15 16 17
18 19 20 21
```

any suggestion ?

Comment: What do you mean by "full"? You mean rows with only 1 column?

Comment: Are you looking for a script using bash, awk, sed, grep etc ? Or can another programming language be used for that like python, perl, php, js or other?

Comment: `awk 'NF > 1' filename`

Comment: Full is completely confusing. According to your expected output you want to omit lines with just one number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ grep -E '[0-9]..' c2.txt
1 2 3 4
8 9
10 11
12 13
15 16 17
18 19 20 21
```